# Sql query for unique result from multiple column

Tags: sql

I need a SQL query for this table (Picture 1) that will give unique results for each columns combination like next table(next picture) there should not be repeated combination, sorry for poor explanation.
[image]

[image]

Result should be like this

Comment: Hint:  `SELECT DISTINCT`.

Comment: Thank you @GordonLinoff it worked...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @Gordon Linoff pointed out, you can use SELECT DISTINCT.  The syntax will look like the following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT class_symbol, section_name, subject 
FROM table
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below query

```
SELECT DISTINCT CLASS_SUMBOL, SECTION_NAME, SUBJECT FROM TABLE_NAME;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below query

```
SELECT DISTINCT CLASS_SUMBOL, SECTION_NAME, SUBJECT
  FROM TABLE_NAME A
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (
           SELECT 1 FROM TABLE_NAME B
            WHERE A.CLASS_SUMBOL < B.CLASS_SUMBOL
              AND A.SECTION_NAME = B.SECTION_NAME
              AND A.SUBJECT = C.SUBJECT
       )
```